# Array to hash conversion and printing the appropriate array

Tags: perl

I have been trying to write a Perl script to take user input names and store them in a hash.

I have used the code below, but it shows error.

This is the question I am trying to answer

> Accept user name as  `first_name<space >last_name` in a single line
>   Accept such multiple users data till the exit is entered
>   store this data in a hash `%emp` by making surname as key and firstname as value
>   Display the users data in ascending sorted order of lastnames.

I am assuming that surnames are unique

```
my $name; 
print "enter name:\n"; 

while ( my $name = lc <STDIN> ) { 
    chomp $name; 
    print "you entered: $name\n"; 

    push @n, $name; 
    last if ( $name eq 'exit' ); 

    $count++; 
    print "enter name :\n"; 
} 

print "count = $count\n"; 

my $r = pop @n;
print "@n\n";

my ($key, $value) = split(' ', @n); 
$emp{$key} = $value; 

while ( my ( $key, $value ) = each %emp ) { 
    my $value; 
    print "$key :$value\n"; 
}
```

I want the code correction.

Comment: 'my $name;
print "enter name:\n";
while(my $name=lc <STDIN>)
{
 chomp $name;
 print "you entered: $name\n";
 push @n,$name;
 last if($name eq 'exit');
 $count++;
 print "enter name :\n"; 
}
print "count = $count\n";
my $r=pop @n;
print "@n\n";
  my ($key,$value) = split(' ',@n);
    $emp{$key} = $value;
while( my( $key, $value ) = each %emp )
{
my $value;
  print "$key :$value\n";
}'

Comment: the code wasn't getting entered in the above question so i put it in the comment

Comment: I entered your code. Please check and adjust/format as you wish

Comment: You need to loop over the array, `foreach my $name (@n)`. Then for each name do the `my ($first, $last) = split ' ', $name` and form a hash pair, `$env{$last} = $first`.  Add `use warnings;` and `use strict;` and declare all variables.  Find a better name for the array than `@n`.  The line `my ($key,$value) = split(' ',@n); ` is not good, cannot `split` on an array. The rest seems fine. Note that you depend on the user's mercy to type their name in correctly, with a space and no commas and such. It'd be good to add checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a **warning** -- parsing names is in general very difficult. All code below works under the strict assumption that each name consists of two words separated by space(s). Also note that without checks you are at a complete mercy of users to enter their names as expected.

---

It appears that you expect `my ($key,$value) = split(' ',@n);` to split each element of `@n` and somehow create the whole hash by the following assignment(s).  The [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) does not work on lists, but it needs a string.  However, you can accomplish this using [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html)

```
my %emp = map { split } @names;  # names must be [word space(s) word]
```

where I changed your array name from `@n` to `@names`.  The `map` takes a list and applies the code in the block `{ }` to one element at a time, and returns the processed list. This is assigned to `%emp`, what may be done since a hash is a list. See [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html).
Since (**if**) each `split` produces two elements the obtained hash has right pairings. Here `split` uses its defaults, so `split` is the same as `split ' ', $_`, where `' '` means any amount of any white space.

I repeate the warnings that names in general *do not* consist of two words. So the above isn't robust in any sense, but it is a generally useful technique.

A more flexible way is to iterate through your list of names

```
my %emp;

foreach my $name (@names) 
{
    my ($first, $last) = split ' ', $name;

    if ($first and $last) {
        $emp{$last} = $first;
    }
    else {
        # print a message, or store 'bad' name on an array
    }
}

print "$_, $emp{$_}\n" for sort keys %emp;
```

You should add thorough checks of the format of submitted names. As a hint I've added a very rudimentary check of whether `split` produced (at least) two words.

You can do the same with `map` by writing a routine for how to process an element and putting that into the block, `my %emp = map { process_name($_) } @names;`. However, error handling will be more difficult.

Given the need to check user input, it would be best to process names as in the loop above but while they are being entered, so the user can be prompted again in case of wrong format.

Answer (score 0):

```
my @n;
loop: while(1) { # get your data with while named as "loop"
    print "enter name: ";
    chomp(my $i = <STDIN>);
    last loop if ($i eq "exit"); # enter to break the "loop"
    push @n, lc $i
}

printf "count = %d\n", $#n + 1;

my %emp = map {
    # split by space and get only first and secound
    my @p = (split)[0,1];
    # check here if everything is defined
    if (defined $p[0]) {
        # add this as key and value
        @p
    } else {
        # skip (this part is important)
        ()
    }
} @n; # converted to hash

my $p = {%emp}; # converted to {hash}ref
```

or even

```
my %emp;
while(1) {
    print "enter name: ";
    chomp(my $i = <STDIN>);

    last if ($i eq "exit");

    my ($k, $v) = split q{ }, lc $i;
    defined $k
        and defined $v
        and $emp{$k} = $v;
}

printf("count = %d\n", scalar keys %emp);
```